# where can a video file be placed and played in android other than sd card?

Tags: android

1.how do we build our own video player in android,it will be helpful if ull can give me some code related to it.

2. other than the sd card where else can we place a video file and paly it.
                       thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to play a video from internal storage (i.e. /data/data/com.yourapp/files) as well but failed; I looked for this question before as well.

But it should work when using a FileDescriptor.

See the following links and discussions:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/a01d415c8e48e0d3

and a solution with code sample here:

http://www.anddev.org/multimedia-problems-f28/videoview-cannot-play-video-from-internal-storage-t16636.html#p52373